# Time complexity of mergesort implementation

Tags: algorithm, sorting, python-3.x, time-complexity, mergesort

[image]

I have an implementation of merge sort.  I'm not too sure about the quality of my implementation, so I ran it with lists of N up to 6000 and graphed the time it took to sort each time.  I know that merge sort should be O(n log n), but my graph looks to be more linear than logarithmic (maybe slightly polynomial).  Am I missing something in my interpretation of this graph?  Furthermore, I'm not sure what to think of the increasing spread as N grows towards 6000.  Does this look right?

Here is an excerpt of some of my data values.  Notice how some of them are precisely the same.  Is this to be expected?

```
N        time (s)

2000    0.023001909
2001    0.023000956
2002    0.023000956
2003    0.028002024
2004    0.023002148
2005    0.023001194
2006    0.024002075
2007    0.023000956
2008    0.023000956
2009    0.023001194
2010    0.023000956
2011    0.023001909
2012    0.024000883
2013    0.023000956
2014    0.022001028
2015    0.024001122
2016    0.023001909
2017    0.024001122
2018    0.024000883
2019    0.023001909
2020    0.023000956
2021    0.024000883
2022    0.023002148
2023    0.024000883
2024    0.024000883
2025    0.024002075
2026    0.023000956
2027    0.024002075
2028    0.023001194
2029    0.024001122
2030    0.023002148
2031    0.024000883
2032    0.023000956
2033    0.024001837
2034    0.023000956
2035    0.024002075
2036    0.028002024
2037    0.024000883
2038    0.024001122
2039    0.024002075
2040    0.024001122
2041    0.023000956
```

Comment: This does not look like constant time. This looks like linear time.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo.  Edited.

Comment: Plot n*log(n) for n = 10...10000.

Answer (score 3):

Your graph is consistent with average O(n log n) behavior - in fact, it appears to fit a curve close to 1.53e-6 * N * log(N)

But to be sure, run your implementation on a series of much larger lists. O(n log n) is only a statement about how the algorithm behaves as n goes to infinity. Your curve may look indistinguishable from a linear and polynomial curve on small inputs, but as the list gets larger and larger, an O(n log n) algorithm will be clearly distinguishable from any O(n^2) algorithm.